# Django randomly sets a single value in couchbase to null during unittest

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, couchbase

I got a very confusing problem.

I wrote a unittest for one of my objects, which contains among others 2 testcases:

```
# coding=utf-8
import unittest

from unittests.helper_functions import *

fix = {}

... Test Data is initialized here

check_if_test_bucket_is_used()
check_if_cb_credentials_are_set()

print "Flushing Bucket"
flush_test_bucket(CB_HOST, CB_USER, CB_PASS)

print "Starting Tests"
create_admin_user()

def testD_post_vehicle_by_driver(self):

    res_vehicle = post_data('/drivers/vehicles', valid_vehicle_0, auth_obj=None,
                             headers={'Authorization': 'WebAuth %s' % fix['token'],
                                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                      'Accept': 'application/json'})

    driver = cb_find_by_key(valid_driver_0_key)
    self.assertIn(valid_obj_0_key, driver[MISSING_KEY])

    print driver

def testE_get_vehicle_by_driver(self):
    res_single_vehicle = get_data('/vehicles/12345', auth_obj=None,
                                   headers={'Authorization': 'WebAuth %s' % fix['token'],
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                            'Accept': 'application/json'})
```

In between `testD` and `testE`, the key `MISSING_KEY` disappears from my database object.

So when I print my driver object in `testD` there is still a value. And in `testE` even before the request to get this vehicle i posted before, the value is already `null` in Couchbase.

The django view is the following:

```
def post(self, request):
    data = request.data
    driver = request.user.details

    vehicle = self.vehicle_bo.create_vehicle_by_driver(data, driver[m.ID])

    return content_response(vehicle, VehicleModel, request, status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I set a breakpoint there at the return, at this moment, the value is still correct in the db.

The function `content_response`:

```
def content_response(response_obj, parser_class, request, status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                 obj_modification_function=None, default='{}'):

if response_obj is None:
    return default

# some json manipulation

response = Response(prepared_obj, status=status_code, headers=get_headers(request))
return response
```

Also here at this the return, the value still remains the same.

From this point, everything is handled by the Response of the rest_framework as far as I understand, which shouldn't do any db manipulation at all.

Anyone an idea, where this can come from?

Some further information:

- Sending all the requests without the unittest framework doesn't result in the null value
- I am flushing the whole couchbase bucket before all the tests A-E are running.
- I am running the tests with PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear, but it sounds like you're initiating a flush operation on a bucket and then immediately trying to use it.

Once critical thing to bear in mind with a flush operation is that it is an *asynchronous* event and may take some time to complete - especially if you are using Couchbase Buckets as it takes time to clean up the data on disk. Generally speaking, you may find more reliable behaviour from **deleting** the bucket and recreating it. This can be accomplished using the [administrative API](http://pythonhosted.org/couchbase/api/admin.html) in the Python SDK.